# Why doesn't the dictionary lookup work in my Python phone book program?

Tags: python, dictionary

I wish to create a Phone Book System in Python as per image below which allows
users to add, delete, update and lookup phone numbers.

[image]

Please see my code below. Options 1,2,3 and 5 work fine, however, option 4 is not working and I'm not sure why. When I add a new entry using option 1 and then immediately try to look up the entry using option 4, it tells me that the entry does not exist when it clearly does.. Am I missing something? (section of code in question starts with "elif selection == 4:")

```
def intro():
    welcome = ("                                     \n"
               "#####################################\n"
               "MYPY PHONE BOOK\n"
               "#####################################\n"
               "1 : Add New Entry\n"
               "2 : Delete Entry\n"
               "3 : Update Entry\n"
               "4 : Lookup Number\n"
               "5 : QUIT\n"
               "")
    selection = input(welcome)
    return int(selection)

phoneBook = {}

while True:
    selection = intro()
    if selection == 1:
        number = input("Enter phone number: ")
        name = input("Enter name: ")
        if number in phoneBook:
            print("                               \n"
                  "* Number already in phonebook *")
        else:
            phoneBook.update({number : name})
            print("                               \n"
                  "* Name and number added to phone book *")
            print(phoneBook)
    elif selection == 2:
        number2 = input("Enter phone number to be deleted: ")
        if number2 in phoneBook:
            phoneBook.pop(number2)
            print("                               \n"
                  "* Number deleted from phone book *")
            print(phoneBook)
        else:
            print("                               \n"
                  "* Number does not exist in phone book *")
    elif selection == 3:
        number3 = input("Enter current phone number: ")
        numberNew = input("Enter updated phone number: ")
        nameNew = input("Enter name: ")
        if number3 in phoneBook:
            phoneBook.pop(number3)
            phoneBook.update({numberNew : nameNew})
            print("                               \n"
                  "* Name and number updated in phone book *")
            print(phoneBook)
        else:
            print("                               \n"
                  "* Number does not exist in phone book *")
    elif selection == 4:
        name4 = input("Enter name: ")
        if name4 in phoneBook:
            for key,value in phoneBook.items():
                if value == name4:
                    print(key)
        else:
            choice = int(input("                                 \n"
                               "Name does not exist in phone book\n"
                               "Enter 1 to add to phoneBook\n"
                               "Enter 2 to return to the menu:\n"
                               ""))
            if choice == 1:
                number4 = input("Enter phone number: ")
                name44 = input("Enter name: ")
                if number in phoneBook:
                    print("                               \n"
                          "* Number already in phonebook *")
                else:
                    phoneBook.update({number4 : name44})
                    print("                               \n"
                          "* Name and number added to phone book *")
                    print(phoneBook)
            elif choice == 2:
                print("                                \n"
                      "* Please make another selection *")
    elif selection == 5:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using names as keys or numbers as keys of your dictionary?

In selection 4, you do `if name4 in phoneBook:...`, however, in other parts of the code, you seem to use the numbers as keys. With dictionaries, you can check if a key is in a dictionary with `key in dictionary`. On the other hand, if you want to check if a value is in a dictionary, you can do:

```
for val in dictionary.values(): 
    if val == value:
        ...
```

Check it out ;)

Comment: Thank you, I added ".values()" to the end and it works now :)